# Optimising my query which uses IFNULL, JOIN and WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query which works perfectly but runs incredibly slowly at times.

```
    SELECT s.ID AS  `Student_ID` , IFNULL( COUNT( f.ID ) , 0 ) AS  `Flags` , IFNULL( COUNT( i.ID ) , 0 ) AS  `Interventions` 
    FROM  `frog_shared`.`student` s
    LEFT JOIN  `frog_flags`.`flags` f ON s.ID = f.`Student_ID` 
    LEFT JOIN  `frog_flags`.`interventions` i ON s.ID = i.`Student_ID` 
    WHERE s.ID
    IN ( 132336 ) 
    GROUP BY s.ID
    ORDER BY s.Surname ASC , s.Firstname DESC
```

Basically, given a list of Student IDs, I want my system to return the number of `Flags` that they've received and the number of `Interventions`.

However, when there's a list of ~30 students, the query is taking nearly a second to run.

The outcome of the query when `EXPLAIN`ed is as follows:

[image: EXPLAIN outcome]

I have indexes on `student.id` and `flags.Student_ID`, so I don't think that's the problem.

How else can I optimise my query?

**UPDATE: `SHOW CREATE` TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE `interventions` (
 `ID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `Visible` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `Student_ID` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.student',
 `Staff_ID` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.staff',
 `Datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Category_ID` int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK intervention_categories',
 `Generation_Type` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '[A]utomated or [M]anual',
 `Reason` text NOT NULL,
 `Status` varchar(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '[O]pen, In [P]rogress, [C]losed',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `flags` (
 `ID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `Student_ID` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.student',
 `Staff_ID` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.staff',
 `Datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Period_ID` int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.periods',
 `Location_ID` int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_shared.locations',
 `Category_ID` int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK flag_categories',
 `Alert_ID` int(11) default NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_alerts.alerts',
 `Action_Taken_Category_ID` int(1) default NULL COMMENT 'FK frog_flags.categories FA',
 `Action_Taken_Status` varchar(1) default NULL COMMENT '[P]ending or [C]omplete',
 `Details` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
 KEY `Student_ID` (`Student_ID`),
 KEY `Staff_ID` (`Staff_ID`),
 KEY `Datetime` (`Datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3669 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `student` (
 `id` varchar(20) default NULL,
 `UPN` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `Firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Year_Group` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `Tutor_Group` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `SEN_Status` varchar(1) default NULL,
 `Flags` varchar(10) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`UPN`),
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `Year_Group` (`Year_Group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question?

Comment: what have you tried so far to optimize that.is it static   IN ( 132336 ) ? or coming from variable.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything - I don't know where to start. The `IN` command is populated dynamically by PHP so it may be `IN( 13141 )` or it could be `IN( 121, 131, 141, 155, 142, 144, ... )` etc.

Comment: @dunc, gives us the SHOW CREATE TABLE for the 3 tables, do you have any indexes on Interventions?

Comment: Added that now @regilero. I don't have any indexes on `interventions` at the moment - because I don't have any data in the table yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest getting rid of the GROUP BY and JOINs, as they don't seem necessary to obtain the result you want.

```
SELECT 
s.ID AS  `Student_ID` , 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `frog_flags`.`flags` f
    WHERE s.ID = f.`Student_ID`
) AS  `Flags` ,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `frog_flags`.`interventions` i
    WHERE s.ID = i.`Student_ID`
) AS  `Interventions` 
FROM  `frog_shared`.`student` s
WHERE s.ID
IN ( 132336 ) 
ORDER BY s.Surname ASC , s.Firstname DESC
```

Make sure to an index on `interventions.Student_ID` and you should be good to go when you get some data in that table.

Let me know if there are any problems with this refactoring.

Comment: Thanks Willem, that appears to be *much* quicker. Could you briefly explain why I don't need the `GROUP BY` and `JOINS` and why those sub-queries are quicker?

Comment: Good answer. Counting by "select clause subquery" is much simpler & clearer than `GROUP BY` structures, and scales -- to retrieve multiple separate counts or functions -- much better.

Comment: As for why faster.. `COUNT(*)` is much faster than `COUNT(column)`, and counting possibly-null rows from the outer join could be slower still. The query does still imply some kind of joins, since the subqueries are _correlated_.. getting rid of the `GROUP BY` and simplifying the `COUNT` clauses are probably the major difference.

Comment: @ThomasW Thanks for the explanation for why the original version was slow. dunc: for my part, I simply looked at the fact that you were querying just 30 records, yet your EXPLAIN had 1417 rows it was looking at. That seemed excessive, and so applied a good optimizing rule of thumb: Structure your query so that you reduce the result set as early in the process as possible. If we can reduce the query to just have to look up 30 rows initially, and each other other values can be counted using indexes, it seemed to me to be pretty good bet that this would be significantly faster.

Comment: It is worth noting that GROUP BY is not by necessarily always slower than select subqueries, even if in this case it was. See http://explainextended.com/2010/01/30/aggregates-subqueries-vs-group-by/ for some additional information.

Comment: @WillemRenzema  The original query had a `WHERE clause` on Student ID and (as a PK) that should have had an index.. MySQL _should_ have been able to restrict Student earlier, it's not clear to me why it didn't/ or chose not to.   Thanks for the link btw.

Comment: Great explanation and discussion Willem and Thomas, much appreciated. Tackling MySQL optimisation is quite tough for me but I'm starting to learn and your indication of "you're querying 30 records but looking up 1417 rows" sits well with an explanation I read in this document: http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/dc-2012/PLDC2012-mysql-query-optimization.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, steps for profilling query is

first execute

```
set profiling=1;
```

then execute the query you want to profile

```
<your query>
```

then execute

```
show PROFILES;
```

it will give result like

```
+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                       |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00057500 | Your query
+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

then exeucte

```
show Profile for query 1;
```

reuslt like

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000105 |
| checking permissions | 0.000014 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000026 |
| System lock          | 0.000006 |
| Table lock           | 0.000051 |
| init                 | 0.000044 |
| optimizing           | 0.000009 |
| statistics           | 0.000019 |
| preparing            | 0.000014 |
| executing            | 0.000213 |
| end                  | 0.000031 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| freeing items        | 0.000030 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000004 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000005 |
```

Tell the result, an check which is taking more time to execute.
and here is a good document for optimizing mysql query: http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/percona-live/dc-2012/PLDC2012-mysql-query-optimization.pdf